# What do these window.external calls mean?

Tags: javascript, external

I recently came across a JavaScript file in our source tree with lots of calls like

```
window.external.getParameter()
window.external.createGUID()
window.external.readStringFromRegistry()
```

and so on and I'm really confused about it.

Are these somehow native calls to the Windows API? And where can I find more information about all the available `window.external` namespace functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look here... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535246(v=vs.85).aspx for info. I presume your site uses .NET?

Perhaps this will help too (possible duplicate): [What is the use of window.external?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694341/what-is-the-use-of-window-external)

Comment: I found that too, but it doesn't have the methods in it that the OP describes. (Well, it might, but they're not documented on that page.)

Comment: @Pointy, [the community additions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535246(v=vs.85).aspx#CommunityContentHeader) say the methods can be defined by the external environment.

Comment: Upvoted! Thanks for this saving me some time here! That's the correct answer! As a best practice it might be be better to include the actual content/answer, since content on the links might change. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here: http://help.dottoro.com/ljisswge.php. It is (in IE) a reference to the 'external' object (you don't say) or (in Firefox) to the 'sidebar' object.

Comment: @downvoter perhaps leave a comment? Or just leave the downvote?