# what is variable "external" meant for in javascript

Tags: javascript

I just found out that there is a variable called **`external`** exists in most browsers except IE. I have 2 question wrt to this

1. what is external - http://jsfiddle.net/EVBjU/
2. IE gives `object doesn't support this property or method` when i do console.log(external). how to fix this, considering it's just a variable

Thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694341/what-is-the-use-of-window-external

Comment: What do you mean by "fix this"? Simply removing the logging statement will remove the error.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan but IE10 is giving giving error for it

Comment: @DavidPärsson i know that but how do i fix a "object doesn't support this property or method" in general

Comment: There is no fix, since what you're doing is not supported. The only fix is to not do it.

Comment: @DavidPärsson is there a way to check if the variable external exists

Comment: @ShadowWizard - IE does have `console.log()`. It's just that in IE it gives an error unless the console is already open (and actually I think MS fixed that in IE10).

Comment: @nnnn it never worked for me, however will delete the comment to avoid confusing people.

Comment: @nnnnnn oh then keeping console.log is bad in ie

Comment: @WebDeveloper using IE is bad. Period. It will always lag behind the real browsers. Luckily enough, people understand that and its usage is ever decreasing.

Comment: @ShadowWizard  http://www.netmarketshare.com/.... IE is way above others(they include china and other asian non-english data )

Comment: @WebDeveloper http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser-ww-monthly-201206-201306 - only 25%, worldwide.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - "Only" 25%? That makes it the second-most popular browser. Even if it was "only" 10% you couldn't really disregard it from a website development point of view.

Comment: @nnnn I don't disregard it, I just dislike it and happy it's becoming less and less popular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"but how do i fix a "object doesn't support this property or method" in general"*

Given an object `obj`, you can test whether property/method `prop` exists with:

```
if ("prop" in obj) {
    // do something with obj.prop
}
```

...noting that the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) will check inherited properties too. To check only for direct properties use:

```
if (obj.hasOwnProperty("prop")) {
    // do something with obj.prop
}
```

> *"is there a way to check if the variable `external` exists"*

In the case of the `external` property you mentioned, it will be a property of `window` if it exists, so:

```
if ("external" in window) {
   // do something
}
```

This `x in window` technique works for global variables including ones provided by the browser and user-defined ones. It doesn't work on local variables.

Comment: can hasOwnProperty be used for functions too

Comment: Yes. In general terms, a JS object's "methods" are really just properties that happen to refer to functions.