# Can I render html in a different control at the same time as a WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am coding a C# forms application where I am creating some html and this is being displayed in a WebBrowser control.

My question is this: Is it possible to render some of the html tags in a different object. By this I mean, I would like to extract some html and display this html somewhere other than the main WebBrowser control.

For example:

I am displaying a jQuery slider, and I am also displaying the value of the slider in a div. If possible, I would like the jQuery slider to be displayed in the WebBrowser control, but the value of the jQuery slider to be displayed in another control.

Can this be done, and if so, what concept do I need to implement?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694341/what-is-the-use-of-window-external

Comment: What do you mean by "a different control"? Is it another WebBrowser control? If not, what type of control is it? Do you want to extract and parse a fragment of the HTML? I'm afraid that you question is a bit too generic for anyone to help you. Also a bit of your code would be helpful.